# solving markup validation errors

Tags: xhtml

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fratingscorner.com%2Fproduct_rating.php%3Falias%3DRashtreeya-Vidyalaya-College-of-Engineering-Mysore-Road-Bangalore%26product%3Dcolleges&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&ss=1&st=1&outline=1&No200=1&verbose=1

hi guys,
              i solved mots of my css errors . there are few errors which i am unable to fix. can some one please help me on  it.

1.Warning  Line 440, Column 1121: cannot generate system identifier for general entity "p"  and similar errors 
2.Error  Line 113, Column 52: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag 
3.Error  Line 441, Column 37752: document type does not allow element "tfoot" here

4. Error  Line 440, Column 80: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Comment: Those are markup errors, not CSS errors.

Comment: Oh come on, there's a good explanation underneath each error. At least use those as starting points for more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML strict requires a fieldset around the form elements:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
     <input />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

also, not all of your ampersands are encoded as & and it's expecting the amp; part (or nbsp; part or whatever code before the ; )

Comment: Henerden - okie. i will solve rest of errors but i need help on these 2 .

1.Error  Line 441, Column 80: Opening and ending tag mismatch: thead line 441 and tr

…ngineering schools in India by "India Today" in 2001. In 2008, the college sto…

2.  Error  Line 440, Column 80: Opening and ending tag mismatch: li line 440 and a

…om:10px;'><a href='/home'>Home</a>&raquo;<a href='/colleges'>colleges</a>&raqu…